# Makefile - pdf generation using LaTeX

Tags: makefile, latex, gnu-make

I wrote a simple makefile to generate pdf using latex and I succeeded.
However, There are 2 point that irritates me:

1. when I run make the output PDF is in the same folder where the makefile is written and I want to change that
2. I want to copy the pdf file generated to another file with another name but I don't know how to do that

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# Generating the file

$(FILE).pdf: $(IMAGES) $(PACKAGES) $(COMMON_TEX_SOURCES) $(FILE_TEX_SOURCES) $(FILE_IMAGES)
    latexmk -lualatex $(FILE)

##############################################################################
    
#rule to generate file
    
file: $(FILE).pdf
```

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To make the target go into a another folder, change the target path:

`some/dir/$(FILE).pdf: $(IMAGES) ...`

To copy the file from one place to another:

```
some/other/dir/$(FILE).pdf: some/dir/$(FILE).pdf
    cp $< $@
```